# How to send a parameter from hidden field in rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am setting my form like this:`<%= hidden_field :room_name, @room.name %>`

in my View I am getting the parameter as

> room_name: !ruby/object:ActionController::Parameters
>       parameters: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
>         Standard Apartment: ''

I just want to get the Standard Apartment Value

Answer (score 1):

If you declared a form with object like

```
<%= form_for(@room, html: {role: "form"}) do |f| %>
```

here `f` is a form object then input field with `value` will look like this

```
<%= f.hidden_field :room_name, value: @room.name %>
```

the output HTML is something like this

```
<input value="Room Name" type="hidden" name="room[room_name]" id="room_room_name">
```

If your form declared without object then it will be

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :room_name, value: @room.name %>
```

Hope it will help other SO user in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out changing my form to this

```
<%= hidden_field_tag "room_name",@room.name %>
```